# UIAlertController gives console error message

Tags: uialertcontroller

i have the following code to present an error message in a UIAlertController in IOS 13. It was working perfectly well in IOS 11, but now i get a console error as below.
Can someone please advise how this can be fixed
thanks.

```
-(void)errorMessage
    {

    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Information",information)
                                                                   message:displaymessage
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",ok)
                                                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

error:

> ```
> > 2020-04-18 00:19:07.958139+0100 TrigCalculator[9298:636378] Warning:
> > Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7fa448043200>  on
> > <UITabBarController: 0x7fa44b008200> which is already presenting
> > <UIAlertController: 0x7fa44787fc00>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

after further investigating this issue, i discovered that my logic elsewhere could potentially cause two alert messages to want to show at the same time.
I didn't want to restructure my logic, so found the following amendment to my code worked.
previous versions of Xcode didn't complain about this, but the latest version picked up the problem and issued the warning.

```
if (self.presentedViewController != nil)
{[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];}
else
{
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

please comment if you feel this is the wrong approach

thanks